# Find the next business day from JSON while loop in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I found a nice little JSON API from [Kayaposoft](https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/json/v2.0/?action=isWorkDay&date=14-04-2019&country=fin) which will give a true/false value if the given day is a work day or not (e.g. Sunday the 14th of April; `isWorkDay: false`). This API is also able to honor our local holidays, like Vappu in Finland, etc.

So, as I try to script this in PowerShell (being the beginner that I am), I quickly realized a problem with the code below. While the code works, it isn't very practical and is dependent on each variable twice (once to set it up and once in the loop).

Is there any way to beautify this code? Can it be made to be more practical and/or to not use each variable twice?

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(11)
$jsonDate = $date.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$jsonRequest = Invoke-WebRequest "https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/json/v2.0/?action=isWorkDay&date=$jsonDate&country=fin" | ConvertFrom-Json

while ($jsonRequest.isWorkDay -ne $true) {

    $date = $date.AddDays(1)
    $jsonDate = $date.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')

    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $jsonRequest = Invoke-WebRequest "https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/json/v2.0/?action=isWorkDay&date=$jsonDate&country=fin" | ConvertFrom-Json

    Write-Host $jsonDate
    Write-Host $jsonRequest

}

Results:
22-04-2019
@{isWorkDay=False}
23-04-2019
@{isWorkDay=True}
```

Comment: Wrap it in a function Get-WorkingDay and return only the enddate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$date = (Get-Date)
# not sure if you really need this ?!?
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# do { ... } while (...) - execute at least once
do {

    $jsonDate = $date.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')    
    $jsonRequest = Invoke-WebRequest "https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/json/v2.0/?action=isWorkDay&date=$jsonDate&country=fin" | ConvertFrom-Json
    $date = $date.AddDays(1)

    Write-Host $jsonRequest
    Write-Host $jsonDate
}
while ($jsonRequest.isWorkDay -ne $true)
```

Comment: I never actually new that do-while loops existed in PowerShell. I was under the impression that you only need while-loops alone, but I guess I must've read it wrong! Thanks! And yea, the `$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(11)` was only to test it out, so that I could land on a non-business day.

Comment: @tobulos1 Powershell is built on top of .NET - it is really close to C# and has the same constructs